# Extract first match from a string of text?

Tags: php

Say I have the following string:

> hello my car is red and my shoe is blue

I want to match the following words:

> blue, red, orange, purple

So it searches the variable for those 4 words, and returns the first one - in my example the word returned would be 'red'. But if the car was blue, the word blue would be returned first as that is the first one it finds out the list of possible matches.

How can I do this?

Comment: Sorry, don't quite get it: if your string is `my car is blue and my shoe is blue`, what should be returned?

Comment: blue, it will find the first one and return

Comment: Ok, but what's the problem then? It's the same code for both your examples.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$str  = 'hello my car is red and my shoe is blue';
$find = 'blue,red,orange,purple';
$pattern = str_replace(',','|',$find);
preg_match('#'.$pattern.'#i',$str,$match);
echo $match[0];
```

If i understood your question correctly.:-)

Comment: Works great, how can I make it case insensitive?

Answer (score 0):

Case sensitive :

```
<?php
$subject = "hello my car is blue and my shoe is blue";                                                                                      
$pattern = '/blue|red|orange|purple/';                                                                                                      
preg_match($pattern, $subject, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);                                                                              
if (!empty($matches)) {                                                                                                                     
  echo 'Matched `' . $matches[0][0] . '` at index `' . $matches[0][1] . '`';                                                                
} else {                                                                                                                                    
  echo 'Nothing matched';                                                                                                                   
} 
?>
```

Case insensitive :

```
<?php
$subject = "hello my car is blue and my shoe is blue";                                                                                      
$pattern = '/blue|red|orange|purple/';                                                                                                      
preg_match(strtolower($pattern), strtolower($subject), $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);                                                                              
if (!empty($matches)) {                                                                                                                     
  echo 'Matched `' . $matches[0][0] . '` at index `' . $matches[0][1] . '`';                                                                
} else {                                                                                                                                    
  echo 'Nothing matched';                                                                                                                   
} 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = 'hello my car is red and my shoe is blue';
$words = array ( 'blue', 'red', 'orange', 'purple' );

function checkForWords ( $a, $b ) {

    $pos = 0;
    $first = 0;
    $new_word = '';

    foreach ( $b as $value ) {
        $pos = strpos( $a, $value );

        # First match
        if ( !$first && $pos ) {
            $new_word = $value;
            $first = $pos;          
        }

        # Better match
        if ( $pos && ( $pos < $first ) ) {
            $new_word = $value;
            $first = $pos;
        }
    }
    return $new_word;

}

echo checkForWords ( $string, $words );
```